# How to display the Two tables entries separately (mine is appearing all entries in one table)

Tags: android, android-sqlite

I have two tables in my database. The entries of table 2 are displaying in one table 1 along with its own entries

For example, if table 1`DATABASE_TABLE` and table 2`DATBASE_TABLE2`has 5 entries EACH, when I enter and view the database, table 1 comes with 10 entries and table to appear empty.

My DatabaseManager.java which handles all operation of database

```
package com.example.draft;

import java.sql.SQLException;

import android.content.ContentValues;
import android.content.Context;

import android.database.Cursor;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteDatabase.CursorFactory;
import android.database.sqlite.SQLiteOpenHelper;
import android.util.Log;

// Class handling all database operations

public class DatabaseManager 
{
//setting variables to use later on in tables and database


public static final String KEY_EXERCISENAME = "exercisename";
public static final String KEY_DURATION = "duration";

private static final String DATABASE_NAME = "MyDatabase";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE = "weekOne";
private static final String DATABASE_TABLE2 = "weektwo";

private static final int DATABASE_VERSION = 3;


//setting variables to reference DbHelper, its Context, and SQLiteDatabase

private DbHelper ourHelper;
private final Context ourContext;
private SQLiteDatabase ourDatabase;

//sub class which creates the database

private static class DbHelper extends SQLiteOpenHelper
{

    public DbHelper(Context context)
    {
        super(context, DATABASE_NAME, null, DATABASE_VERSION);

        // TODO Auto-generated constructor stub
    }

    //method to create the database and table

    @Override
    public void onCreate(SQLiteDatabase db) 
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub
        db.execSQL
        ("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE + " (" +
            KEY_EXERCISENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_DURATION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

        db.execSQL
        ("CREATE TABLE " + DATABASE_TABLE2 + " (" +
            KEY_EXERCISENAME + " TEXT NOT NULL, " +
            KEY_DURATION + " TEXT NOT NULL);"
        );

    }

    //method to show the table if it exists

    @Override
    public void onUpgrade(SQLiteDatabase db, int oldVersion, int newVersion)
    {
        // TODO Auto-generated method stub

        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE);
        db.execSQL("DROP TABLE IF EXISTS " + DATABASE_TABLE2);

        onCreate(db);
    }

}

public DatabaseManager(Context c)
{
    ourContext = c; 
}

public DatabaseManager open() 
{
    ourHelper = new DbHelper(ourContext);
    ourDatabase = ourHelper.getWritableDatabase();
    return this;    
}

//creating entry in table for treadmill in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long createEntry(String treadmillTimings) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //enterting each exercise name corresponding to their respective edit Texts

    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Treadmill");
    cv.put(KEY_DURATION, treadmillTimings);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv);

}

//creating entry in table for stepperTimings in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry1 (String stepperTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stepper");
    cv1.put(KEY_DURATION, stepperTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv1);

}

//creating entry in table for Stationary Rowing in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry2 (String stationaryRowingTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv2.put(KEY_DURATION, stationaryRowingTimings);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv2);

}

//creating entry in table for exercise bike in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry3 (String exerciseBikeTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv3 = new ContentValues();
    cv3.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Exercise Bike");
    cv3.put(KEY_DURATION, exerciseBikeTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv3);

}

//creating entry in table for elliptical trainer in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week1createEntry4 (String ellipticalTrainerTimings)
{
    ContentValues cv4 = new ContentValues();
    cv4.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv4.put(KEY_DURATION, ellipticalTrainerTimings);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE, null,cv4);

}

//displaying/reading data in the table using cursor

public String week1getData() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DURATION};
    Cursor cur = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    //creating a result(string type variable) to store the text and display it.

    String result = "";

    int iExerciseName = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    int iDuration = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_DURATION);

    // cursor start from the first position, keeps moving to the next as long as the position in not after that last.

    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext())
    {
        /*getting the rows, exercise name and duration in the tables of database and setting it to result. 
          .The next time it loops, it will still have the previous result*/

        result = result + cur.getString(iExerciseName) + "                            " + cur.getString(iDuration) + "\n";
    }

    return result;

}

public long week2createEntry(String treadmillTimingsweek2) 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub

    ContentValues cv = new ContentValues();

    //Entering each exercise name corresponding to their respective edit Texts

    cv.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Treadmill");
    cv.put(KEY_DURATION, treadmillTimingsweek2);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null,cv);

}

//creating entry in table for stepperTimings in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week2createEntry1 (String stepperTimingsweek2)
{
    ContentValues cv1 = new ContentValues();
    cv1.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stepper");
    cv1.put(KEY_DURATION, stepperTimingsweek2);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null,cv1);

}

//creating entry in table for Stationary Rowing in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week2createEntry2 (String stationaryRowingTimingsweek2)
{
    ContentValues cv2 = new ContentValues();
    cv2.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv2.put(KEY_DURATION, stationaryRowingTimingsweek2);

    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null,cv2);

}

//creating entry in table for exercise bike in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week2createEntry3 (String exerciseBikeTimingsweek2)
{
    ContentValues cv3 = new ContentValues();
    cv3.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Exercise Bike");
    cv3.put(KEY_DURATION, exerciseBikeTimingsweek2);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null,cv3);

}

//creating entry in table for elliptical trainer in table week 1 with the help of ContentValues

public long week2createEntry4 (String ellipticalTrainerTimingsweek2)
{
    ContentValues cv4 = new ContentValues();
    cv4.put(KEY_EXERCISENAME, "Stationary Rowing");
    cv4.put(KEY_DURATION, ellipticalTrainerTimingsweek2);
    return ourDatabase.insert(DATABASE_TABLE2, null,cv4);

}

public String week2getData() 
{
    // TODO Auto-generated method stub
    String[] columns = new String[]{KEY_EXERCISENAME, KEY_DURATION};
    Cursor cur = ourDatabase.query(DATABASE_TABLE2, columns, null, null, null, null, null);

    //creating a result(string type variable) to store the text and display it.

    String result = "";

    int iExerciseName = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_EXERCISENAME);
    int iDuration = cur.getColumnIndex(KEY_DURATION);

    // cursor start from the first position, keeps moving to the next as long as the position in not after that last.

    for(cur.moveToFirst(); !cur.isAfterLast(); cur.moveToNext())
    {
        /*getting the rows, exercise name and duration in the tables of database and setting it to result. 
          .The next time it loops, it will still have the previous result*/

        result = result + cur.getString(iExerciseName) + "                            " + cur.getString(iDuration) + "\n";
    }

    return result;

}
```

The textView that I am displaying `DATABASE_TABLE` entries is`android:id = @+id/dbinfo`and `DATABASE_TABLE2` entries in `android:id = "@+id/week2dbinfo`

What I want is `DATABASE_TABLE` shows 5 entries in `android:id = @+id/dbinfo`and `DATABASE TABLE2` shows 5 entries in  `android:id = "@+id/week2dbinfo`

Please help

Comment: Have you looked at the actual table? Maybe you're not inserting into the correct table to begin with. That said, your database schema isn't very good. Why not put everything in *one* table, add a `weekId`, and then you can query based on `weekId=1` or `weekId=2` -- and you don't have to add a table for each week in the future.

Comment: I did the way you sugested me but still not appearing as its intended

Comment: Considering that you have no primary key on either of your tables, is it possible you're inserting the values twice? If not, please add the code where you actually display the data.

Comment: Thanks but I managed to figure it out. I was calling method of display entries of week 2 by using the method of week1(week1getData()), so changed it to week2getData() n it worked fine but cheer for the suggestions mate :) hav a good 1

Answer (score 0):

I was calling method of display entries of week 2 by using the method of week1 `week1getData()`, so changed it to `week2getData`